# I made a command by mistake

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

By mistake I made the wrong command in shell , and now i cant find my files.

the command i made was:

```
mv file.ext ..\..\out
```

instead of making

```
mv file.ext ../../out
```

Where should I search for my files.

Comment: Don't you have a file `....out` in your current directory ?

Comment: your new file is renamed to "....out"

Comment: I do have a ....out file but I have used that command for many files.. Where can I find all of my files.

Answer (score 1):

The `\` get stripped out if you're using bash, so that command renames the file to "....out".  Use `ls -la` to list it.

Comment: The problem is, that i moved many files in that way.. Just one ....out file there

Comment: Sadly, they are lost, unless `....out` is a directory. Time to find out what backups are available.